# PHP Error reporting on demand

Tags: php, iis

In PHP how do you make it so that it will only display errors when using the error_reporting() function. Currently the IIS PHP application is set to 'Production machine'. If I change it to Development machine it will print out all errors even without error_reporting().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the behavior I wanted using:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

`error_reporting` may be set by your application and override the php.ini setting.

In any case, you should *never* turn it off.

Instead, change `display_errors` to `Off` in php.ini, or in your code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Comment: I have error_reporting in php.ini set to the default 'E_ALL & ~DEPRECATED' and display_errors set to Off. but when I put error_reporting(-1); at the top of a error filled php file it just displays an empty page.

Comment: The errors are loged in my log file though, it would just be more convenient to have them on the page while I develop.

Comment: @Raymond: Not sure what you want here. You want to show them or hide them? Can you clarify?

Comment: I want them to only be shown when I have error_reporting(-1); at the top of a php file.

Comment: Then that's the wrong approach. Don't change error_reporting, change display_errors as demonstrated above.

Answer (score 1):

On your "Production machine" you can toggle the error_reporting on and off... directly in your PHP script.

You can also find this in your php.ini file on your server to set the default.

```
<?php

// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
// This is the default value set in php.ini
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
error_reporting(0);
```

work for you?